# Disappearing events in FullCalendar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar made through fullcalendar.js
It has external calendar events that you can add to it via drag and drop.

My problem is that events disappear when I move back one month and then return to the month I was just looking at.

Here is the calendar initialisation code:

```
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({       
                editable: true,                  
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',      
                    center: 'title',              
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek'     
                },                               
                events: //some events
                ignoreTimezone: false,                              
                eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc){
                    //do stuff                        
                },                                
                eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc,jsEvent,ui, view) {
                    //do stuff
                },
                droppable: true,
                drop: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var dropped = $this.data('eventobject');
                    var dropped2 = $.extend({} , dropped);
                    dropped2.title = $this.html();
                    dropped2.start = date;
                    dropped2.allDay = (dropped.allDay || allDay);
                    $parent.text(renderDate(date, "MDY", "/"));

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', dropped2, true);
                    iosocket.emit("calendar", {calEvent: finitise(dropped2)});
                    $this.remove();
                }
            });
```

You will notice I have "sticky" set to true in the renderEvent section. When this is "false", only new events dissapear when changing months - this is expected behaviour.

However, with sticky set to "true" all the events dissapear, whether they were in the inital set or not.
I get a console error saying "events[i] is null", which seems to indicate to me that the calendar events are moving out of scope, but I have no idea how.

Seems to only occur when scrolling between months; when scrolling over weeks, everything appears to be normal until you hit the edge of a month- then the error is encountered again

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
Problem was that the dropped2 event was being changed after rendering.

The finitise method removes circular references (e.g. A has child B, B has child C, C has child A).

What I did not realise (though I should have, because is is the motivation behind finitise method) is that render Event creates circular references that are required by fullCalendar.

As I was calling finitise AFTER rendering, the structure of the event is not valid for subsequent renders that happen automatically when you change months in the calendar.

Calling finitise before the renderEvent call resolves this issue, as the renderEvent will add the circular references to the finitised object (and doesn't cause problems with socketio as the finitise object has already been sent through iosocket).